# Python, Lists associated with each other

Tags: python

Im looking for thoughts on solving what im trying to achieve.

Im looking to do a dns query in python say for instance;

```
 import adns

 c=adns.init()
 c.synchronous("www.google.com", adns.rr.A)
```

Im looking to store the output;

```
(0, 'www.l.google.com', 1167604334, ('216.239.37.99', '216.239.37.104'))
```

in a list, but the list would need to be associated with teh domain name.

So www.google.com would need to be associated with the common name and ip addresses. So if I had a list of domains they are all printed with their relevant data.

Can you have a list inside another list? Abit like a database i guess?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: lists can hold other lists, yes. as shown by the the tuple in a tuple your output has. lists are similar to a tuple, but can be mutated

Answer (score 0):

yep, a dict will do

```
data = []
domain = "www.google.com"
data[domain] = c.synchronous(domain, adns.rr.A)
print data
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so if i have a list of Domains in the domain variable how do i print data for an individual domain?

Comment: @LearningCode `print data[domain]`

Comment: Im using a file as input from user (this will be subdomain) and input from user to get a value for domain variable. How do I concatenate these into this function?     `def addcheck(file, domain, *args):
  data =[]
  c=adns.init()
  for sub in file:
     data[file + "." + domain] = c.synchronous(file + "." domain, adns.rr.A)
     print data`